# Haskell chain functions based on separate conditions

Tags: function, haskell, chain

Is there an efficient/easy way, when chaining functions applied to one argument, to only apply functions that fulfill their requirements in order to be applied? E.g.:

I have 1 argument 'Obj' and 3 functions: func1, func2, func3. Each have their own requirements which need to be fulfilled in order for the function to be applied to the argument as well. E.g. pseudo-code:

```
(if condition1 then func1) . (if condition2 then func2) . (if condition3 then func3) Obj
```

So if all conditions are qualified, all 3 functions would be applied to Obj.

Is there any way I can do this properly?

Comment: What if `condition2` is not met. What should happen then?

Comment: Then func2 should not be applied to the argument, as in: func2 should not be executed and only func1 and func3 should be executed with as argument Obj (IF they fulfill their conditions, otherwise none and just Obj should be returned)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you have a missing `$` before `Obj`.  I think in answer to your question, you just need to supply an `else` clause:

```
(if c0 then f0 else id) $ (if c1 then f1 else id) $ (if c2 then f2 else id) $ arg
```

Comment: Aah right! I forgot about the id function and thought there might've been an easier/more efficient way for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can define a list of functions in a chain as follows

```
let fChain = [f1 | cond1] ++ [f2 | cond2] ++ ....
```

then evaluate the list like this

```
let result = fChain `apply` value
```

where

```
apply = foldl (.) id
```

Of course, the type of each fn must be `(a->a)` (because for `condn==False`, we substitute in `id`)

Comment: Why not instead use `apply fs conds = foldl (.) id . filter fst . zip conds fs` if you're going to go that route?  You'll have better performance with long chains of functions since you won't be doing concatenations, and then you have `apply :: [a -> a] -> [Bool] -> a -> a`.

Comment: @bheklilr- Because I find `fChain = [f1 | cond1] ++ [f2 | cond2] ++ ....` really easy to read.  The number of functions that I would chain together would typically be 10 or less, so performance loss would never even occur to me for this (although if it were in the inner loop, I might rethink).  I suppose an apply with type `[((a->a), Bool)]->a->a` might be readable though.  I'd probabaly avoid `apply :: [a -> a] -> [Bool] -> a -> a` though, because the functions and conditions would be separate, and you could accidentally mismatch.